# Reducing ArrayList with Math.log on all elements

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an arrayList of Floats and I want to use the Math.log-method on all elements in the array and then add them together. Something like this:

```
var doubleValue = floatArrayList.stream()
        .reduce( 1.0, (a, b) -> Math.log(a) + Math.log(b));
```

My result is `doubleValue == NaN`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's in your list?  Just zero elements?

Comment: One problem...say you have a list of three elements `a`, `b`, and  `c`. You are currently calculating `log(c) + log(log(b) + log(log(a) + log(1)))`...or something like that because you are repeatedly taking the log of the sum. I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: Why don't you `map()` the values to `Math.log()` first and then sum them? Something like `floatArrayList.stream().mapToDouble(Math::log).sum()` - probably easier to read and use than `reduce(0.0, (sum, value) -> sum + Math.log(value))`.

Comment: consider (better naming): `reduce(subtotal, (subtotal, x) -> ...)` , then (applied to your use case) better: `reduce(0f, (subtotal, x) -> subtotal + Math.log(x))` ;)

Comment: While folding stream elements via `Math.log()` at some point logarithm becomes equal to zero, and I guess logarithm of zero would be resolved as *Negative Infinity*. Then try to calculate `Math.log(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)` and see what you'll get.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko More likely the OP is taking the log of a negative number. But the problem is deeper because they are taking the log of each partial sum.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're trying to do.

```
 List<Float> floats = List.of(1.f, 3.f, 2.4f, 5.7f, 10.f);
 
 float d1 = 0;
 for(float d : floats) {
     d1 += Math.log(d);
 }
 System.out.println((double)d1);
 double d2 = floats.stream().reduce(
         0.f,  (a, b) ->a + (float)Math.log(b));
 
 double d3 = floats.stream().parallel().reduce(
         0.f,  (a, b) ->a + (float)Math.log(b), (threadSums, tResult)->threadSums + tResult);
 
 
 System.out.println(d2);
 System.out.println(d3);
```

prints

```
6.01713228225708
6.01713228225708
6.01713228225708
```

Note:  The main problem I had earlier was not realizing the the default combiner was the provided accumulator.  Here is the source code:

```
@Override
public final P_OUT reduce(final P_OUT identity, final BinaryOperator<P_OUT> accumulator) {
        return evaluate(ReduceOps.makeRef(identity, accumulator, accumulator));
}
```

Since the provided accumulator `mutates` the value by taking the `log` it would also `mutate` the different results from the threads. So an explicit `combiner` must be provided as was done above in the updated answer.

Comment: The first is in full agreement with the docs and contract now. For the second I think you need `doubles.stream().map(Math::log).reduce(0.,  (a, b) -> a +  b)` (or equivalent).

Comment: Well, I can do that.  I guess I don't understand why putting taking the `log` in the reduction operation is a problem.   Even if I run it in parallel with a combiner I would think it should work.   I will need to do some testing to understand this better.

Comment: Not that I can explain in detail. `doubles.stream().parallel().reduce(0.,  (a, b) -> a +  Math.log(b))` just gave me 0.6935014689306679, which is pretty far away from your (correct) result.